# DbContext.Set<T>().SqlQuery and DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T> returning different results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

**SQL query:**

```
SELECT 0 AS Id,
       u.UserID AS UserId,
       u.first_name AS FirstName,
       u.last_name AS LastName,
       uf.uf_facility_id AS FacilityId
FROM ...
```

**Entity** no additional mappings, simply defined property in DbContext - public `DbSet<UserFacility> UserFacilities { get; set; }`:

```
public class UserFacility
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int FacilityId { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext.Set().SqlQuery**

Returns list of `UserFacility` where `UserId` is duplicated for each item and it equals to the `UserId` value for the first row e.g.:

```
Id  UserId  FirstName   LastName    FacilityId
0   33057   ggtest  2   3938
0   33057   QaAuOne TestOne 3938
0   33057   QaAuOne TestOne 3928
```

**DbContext.Database.SqlQuery**

Returns expected results (same what I get when run this query in SSMS).

```
Id  UserId  FirstName   LastName    FacilityId
0   33057   ggtest  2   3938
0   33098   QaAuOne TestOne 3938
0   33098   QaAuOne TestOne 3928
```

Can someone please explain what the heck is happening and how I can make `DbContext.Set<T>().SqlQuery` to return correct data? I am using EntityFramework 6.2.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your query doesn't make much sense. Why would you have an Id forced to return 0?  If the UserId is effectively the unique key for the UserFacility table then treat ID as an NotMapped property and set the PK to UserId. EF is likely getting confused by how you have the PK defined. Results like this commonly happen where you define a PK that is insufficient to uniquely identify a row.

Comment: @StevePy yeah, I managed to resolve this by removing Id prop and marking UserId and FacilityId with Key and Column(Order = x) attributes. Unfortunately, I did not bother to update SO. If you can format this as an answer I will accept it to thank you for your input. Thanks.